# Bash Detect Mounted Folder as Directory

Tags: linux, bash

I am creating this bashs script that has a folder path, passed as a paramter.

And if it detects that paramter is a directory, then it uses it as a path for script work.

But for some reason, it denies treating this folder path as a directory.

Which has befuddled me to no end.

This is a mounted external 3tb hard drive, works fine, no issues, what so ever.

But is mounted as /media/wdmybook/

I have this testing script to help me debug and identify the problem.

```
#!/bin/bash
DIR="/media/wdmybook/folder"

if grep -qs '$DIR' /proc/mounts; then
    echo "It's mounted."
else
echo "It's not mounted."
fi

if [ ! -d "$DIR" ]; then
    echo "Directory does not exist!"
elif [ "$DIR" != -d ]; then
    echo "Not a Directory"
else
    echo "Path is okay"
fi
```

But everytime I run it, it detects the path as an invalid directory, and it is not mounted.

So what am I missing or not seeing?

Is this a permissions issue?

I am running this on Debian Wheezy XFCE.

Comment: You wrote it es mounted as  `/media/wdmybook/` but *DIR* is set to `/media/wdmybook/folder` in the script, maybe that is the issue. BTW: `elif [ "$DIR" != -d ]; then` looks suspicious too, as `!=`will test for string inequality.

Comment: /media/wdmybook is the root path of the mounted external drive, /media/wdmybook/folder is a folder inside the mounted external drive. It is a directory, but somehow bash can not detect it as a directory. This is very confusing, lol.

Comment: Also, `grep -qs '$DIR' /proc/mounts` won't work. Single quotes inhibit parameter expansion; you need double quotes: `grep -qs "$DIR" /proc/mounts`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should rewrite your if condition to something like that:

```
if [ ! -e "$DIR" ]; then
    echo "Directory does not exist!"
elif [ ! -d "$DIR" ]; then
    echo "Not a Directory"
else
    echo "Path is okay"
fi
```

For details see `man test`

Comment: The response I get is, Directory does not exist. The same as before.

Comment: Weird. Perhaps you should paste the output of `mount` into your question. You don't need to paste the whole thing, just the line that relates to `/media/wdmybook`

Comment: /dev/sdc1 /media/wdmybook fuseblk rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096 0 0